# With reactJs and react.fluentui controls, how do I detect leaving a TableRow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a reactJs form using the Fluent controls and Table to help layout the form (https://react.fluentui.dev/?path=/docs/components-table--default)

Within a row of the table, I have three buttons - Save, Save As, Delete that save/delete the content of the table above them. When SaveAs is clicked, it shows a further table row just below the buttons to accept the new name with OK and Cancel buttons (instead of popping up a modal dialog). The react function for that row is the following (with the Table configured to be rendered as  rather than  elements, so I can control the column widths with the flex attributes):

```
  function getNewNameRow() {
    const inputId = useId("newName");
    const styles = useStyles();
    return (
      showNewName && (
        <TableRow className={styles.tableNameRow} width="100%" onBlur={btnSaveAsCancelClick}>
          <TableCell className={styles.tableNoResize}>
            <label id={inputId}>New name:</label>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell>
            <Input
              id={inputId}
              className={styles.input}
              aria-labelledby={inputId}
              onChange={(e) => {
                checkNewName(e);
              }}
            />
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell className={styles.tableNoResize}>
            <Button
              appearance="primary"
              size="small"
              icon=<Checkmark20Filled />
              onClick={btnSaveAsOKClick}
              disabled={!enableSaveAsOK}
            ></Button>
            <Button
              appearance="secondary"
              size="small"
              icon=<Dismiss20Filled />
              onClick={btnSaveAsCancelClick}
            ></Button>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      )
    );
  }
```

so I can show/hide it by toggling the showNewName state.

I can't work out how to manage the focus. What I want to happen is:

- If type a name in the input box, then click the OK button (in the same row), the Save code executes, saves the data and hides the New Name row.
- If I type a name in the input box, then click the Cancel button (in the same row), the Cancel code executes and hides the New Name row.
- If I click on the form anywhere outside the table row, it behaves the same as Cancel, hiding the NewName row.
- I should be able to tab between the Input, OK and Cancel buttons without it hiding, but hide if I tab out of those 3 (or trap me in there until I click Cancel)

As you can see, I was hoping to do this with the onBlur of the TableRow, but that fires as soon as I leave the Input box, even if it's only to click the OK button - so the OK button is gone before it's clicked.

I'm a bit of a newbie with ReactJs, Fluent and these controls, so please assume I know nothing!